# Accessing scope from a JSONP callback

Tags: angularjs

I'm dealing with a web service that is not working with the `JSON_CALLBACK` logic (it replaces the dot in the callback name), so I am having to come up with my own callback.

My problem is that I am trying to set a $rootScope variable to the data I got from the callback, but not I don't know how to do that.

Please see my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ARLtF/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$rootScope` to the `run` block so you can assign the fetched data to a property, and pass in `$window` as well, to hold the JSONP callback.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.run(function($http, $window, $rootScope) {

    $window.process_time = function (data) {
        $rootScope.time = data;
    };

    $http.jsonp('http://www.timeapi.org/mst/now.json?callback=process_time');
});
```

---

[<kbd>**Demo !**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/e2pDS/)